# Android Hilt cyclic dependencies

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have cyclic dependencies error in the below sample code:

MyFragment.class

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment():MyInterface{
...

@Inject
lateinit var myClass: MyClass

.....
}
```

I need to get a callback from MyClass into MyFragment.

MyClass.class

```
class MyClass @Inject constructor(val myInterface:MyInterface){
....
}
```

MyInterface.class

```
interface MyInterface{}
```

MyModule

```
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class MyModule {
   @Binds
  abstract fun provideCallback(callback: MyFragment): MyInterface
}
```

Comment: Why you want to inject this?